# Brew Hadoop Hbase install older versions

Tags: hadoop, hbase, homebrew

If I install Hadoop and Hbase:

```
brew install hadoop hbase
```

I get the following versions:

**hadoop: 2.6.0**

**hbase: 0.98.8**

But need the versions:

**hadoop: 1.1.2**

**hbase: 0.94.8**

How can I install older versions through the Brew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have hadoop & hbase installed using **brew** unlink them using:

```
brew unlink hadoop
brew unlink hbase
```

Now try and search for a specific version of hadoop and hbase using **versions** subcommand:

```
$ brew versions hadoop | grep 1.1.2
1.1.2    git checkout d133e18 /usr/local/Library/Formula/hadoop.rb

$ brew versions hadoop | grep 0.94.8
0.94.8   git checkout 33fdb3e /usr/local/Library/Formula/hbase.rb
```

Now go to `/usr/local/Library` and check out (`git checkout`) the versions you need:

```
git checkout d133e18 /usr/local/Library/Formula/hadoop.rb
git checkout 33fdb3e /usr/local/Library/Formula/hbase.rb
```

Finally perform a `brew install hadoop hbase` to get the versions you want.